# How to close a windows form after message box OK is clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms

Program has two forms: Login and the main form after login.
Upon launching of the program, it connects to the database and checks if there is a new version available, if so, it instantly displays a MessageBox letting the user know to download the new version.

When the user clicks OK, the application needs to be closed so the user can no longer use it until the new version is downloaded. The problem is, after clicking okay, the login form is still shown. My code for the class is below:

```
 DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("FleetTrack™ update required.\n\nA new version of FleetTrack™ is available on your Driver Hub. You must download"
        + " the latest update to use FleetTrack™.", "FleetTrack™ Update Required", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        if (dialog == DialogResult.OK)
        {


            Application.ExitThread();
        }
```

Not too sure what I need to do. The application successfully shows the pop-up if the version running is different than what is shown in the database, but after clicking OK it just loads up the login form like normal.

Comment: This code is in what module? Please show the entire startup code.

Comment: Why not just call `Close()` on the login form?

Comment: High odds that you didn't call Application.Run() yet.  So there's nothing to exit yet.  Use the debugger, set breakpoints.  Environment.Exit() always works.

Comment: Just switched the code up a bit. I think you're right @HansPassant. It gives an exception now in the Main with the following highlighted: `Application.Run(new Login());`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Application.Exit() and not Application.ExitThread()

And if you are displaying the Dialog box before Application.Run(), then all you need to ensure is that you do not call the Application.Run() if a version update is required.

```
if (updateRequired)
{
    DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("FleetTrack™ update required.\n\nA new version of FleetTrack™ is available on your Driver Hub. You must download"
+ " the latest update to use FleetTrack™.", "FleetTrack™ Update Required", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    if (dialog == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
} else 
    Application.Run(new Login());
```

updateRequired is a boolean you maintain to check if an app update is required.

Comment: is there anything wrong with simply adding a `await Task.Delay(100);` before the `Application.Exit();` line in the form? I tried this simple fix and it closes the program just fine now. It gives it that little bit of time for the Application.Run code to work and then it is able to close the program. Is there anything wrong with doing things this way?